# UIStepper in UIWebView - iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, uiwebview, uistepper

I have been looking to use a UIStepper to increase and decrease font size in a WebView.

```
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '140%'"];
```

I want it so when I press the plus it takes it increases font size by 40% and when you press the minus it decreases the font size by 40%. So if I press the plus then the minus it takes it back to how it was and if i press the minus again it decreases the font size another 40%.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you have so far? It's hard to help without current information /context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textFontSize = 140;


NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'",
                      textFontSize];


[self.articleWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```